# Anyconnect Start Before Logon over Cell

Tags: anyconnect, cellular

Is it possible to enable Start Before Logon on when using Cisco AnyConnect on Windows 11 over a cellular connection?  At least in my testing it doesn't seem to work, but it connects after logging in. Reading into it some more and the Cisco Network Access Manager it seems wired connections or WiFi connections are supported but I don't see any mention of cellular?